# Number of ways to parenthesize Matrix Multiplication: Why isn't it $(n-1)!$

Tags: combinatorics

I encountered this problem in [CLRS](http://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262046305/introduction-to-algorithms/) second edition chapter 15.2 "Matrix-chain multiplication". We are trying to solve a problem that requires "parenthesize" a matrix product (e.g. if you are multiplying matrices $A_1A_2A_3A_4$ then $(A_1A_2)(A_3A_4)$ and $((A_1A_2)A_3)A_4$ are two different ways to parenthesize the matrix multiplication so the order of operation are different).

On page 333 it says that the number of different ways to *fully* parenthesize a sequence of $n$ matrices, $P(n)$ is given by:

$P(n) = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } n = 1 \\
\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}P(k)P(n-k) &\text{if } n \ge 2
\end{cases}$

However when I'm doing my own calculation I am getting $P(n) = (n-1)!$. The reason I have is follows:

- For the sequence of $n$ matrices, you can choose any two consecutive matrices to multiply together. You have $n-1$ choices;
- For each of the $n-1$ choices, you now have $n-2$ different choices (because you multiplied the two matrices from the last choice into one, so you have one less)
- For each of the $n-2$ choices you now have $n-3$ choices etc...
- Thus the total number of choices you have is $(n-1)(n-2)...1 = (n-1)!$

I don't understand why my answer doesn't match the one on the book. Which part of my reasoning is wrong? Am I counting duplicates maybe? Or maybe when we expand the recursion we will get the same answer as mine?

Answer (score 7):

You are counting some possibilities multiple times. For example, if we want to parenthesize the product of four matrices $ABCD$, your computation will count these two ways as distinct:

1. Multiply $A$ and $B$, then multiply $C$ and $D$, and finally multiply the two multiplication results.
2. Multiply $C$ and $D$, then multiply $A$ and $B$, and finally multiply the two multiplication results.

But actually, they are referring to the same expression: $(AB)(CD)$.

Comment: But matrix multipivation is , in general , not commutative, so we have to multiply in the correct order.